# Shisha Asar Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred sixteen?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shibud of Mitrayim was 116 years (Rashi Vaera 6:16 quoting Seder Olam Rabbah):

The years of Levi are counted to show the shibud did not start until the last of the brother passed on- and that was Levi.

The brothers (except for Binyamin) were born within 6 years of eachother.  Subtract 2 years for Reuven and Shimon.  That made Levi 4 years older than Yosef, who was the last of the six years.  Yosef was 30  when he came before Paroah and Levi 34, + 7 years of sava, + 2 years of famine, making Levi 43 when he and his family arrived in Mitzrayim- the start of the 210 years. Levi was 137 when he died, making his stay in Mitzrayim 94 years and that was the start of the shibud.  210 - 94= 116.

Answer (score 1):

Parshas Beshalach has 116 Pesukim

Answer (score 1):

It was taught in a Baraisa in the name of R' Nechemiah: For nearly **116** years the fire was aflame in the Altar but nevertheless it's wood did not burn and it's copper did not melt...

Vayikra Rabbah 7:5